# frame-src and manifest-src are being ignored in content security policy

Tags: reactjs, webpack, amazon-cloudfront, content-security-policy

I've built a single-page app with React.js and hosted it on AWS behind a Cognito login page (see [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-using-cookies-protect-your-amazon-cloudfront-content-from-being-downloaded-by-unauthenticated-users/) and [this Lambda template](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/create/app?applicationId=arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:520945424137:applications/cloudfront-authorization-at-edge)). This triggered errors that complained about the lack of a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), so I [added](https://medium.com/@nrshahri/csp-cra-324dd83fe5ff) the `csp-html-webpack-plugin` to my standard `create-react-app` setup using `react-app-rewired`.

**config-overrides.js**

```
const { override } = require("customize-cra");
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require("csp-html-webpack-plugin");

const cspConfigPolicy = {
  "default-src": "'none'",
  "base-uri": "'self'",
  "object-src": "'none'",
  "script-src": ["'self'"],
  "style-src": ["'self'"],
  "img-src": ["'self'"],
  "frame-src": ["https://drive.google.com/"],
  "manifest-src": ["'self'"],
};

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
  }

  return config;
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin),
};
```

**.env**

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
```

This results in a `/build/index.html` file with a `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag and without any inline JavaScript or CSS, but it still didn't work perfectly. There were still lots of errors about inline styles (presumably CSS being injected by React components). I was able to bypass those by manually removing the nonce that followed `style-src 'self'` and replacing it with `'unsafe-inline';`. This isn't ideal, but I think it's acceptable for my app.

```
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-4vMiP/MSTpSmzZRvWpahlQ==' 'nonce-ttbsbXQ2ka2E/pUj4y8w0g==' 'nonce-SPF0ZOWgqYX6X7cGjFBdNQ=='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; frame-src https://drive.google.com; manifest-src 'self';"
    />
```

The bigger problem is that, even though policies for `frame-src` and `manifest-src` are set in the meta tag, the browser doesn't seem to be reading them. It still outputs the following errors and refuses to display cross-domain content in iframes.

*Refused to frame 'https://drive.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

*Refused to load manifest from 'https://mysubdomain.cloudfront.net/manifest.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'manifest-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

All the other content is loading correctly now. The errors don't appear when I run the app locally or host it without Cognito authorization.

**Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Comment: I tried editing the meta tag to `default-src 'self' https://drive.google.com;`, but the errors still complain that `it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"`. Strange.